# phpmyadmin console error "Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined"

Tags: phpmyadmin, console

i have problem in phpmyadmin after install vesta control panel, in console i get error "Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined" and "Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function"

Web Server

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 OpenSSL/1.0.1f
Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.52
PHP extension: mysqli

Database Server

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.52-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: Were you able to find the resolution for this issue? Even I am facing this issue so wanted to confirm what was the resolution.